# What does normative and non-normative mean in reference to XML

Tags: xml, specifications, w3c

What does normative and non-normative mean in reference to XML documents as stated in the w3.org document? It really is not explained and just assumes we know what it means. Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

"Normative" means that it's an official formal part of the specification; non-normative means that it's there to be helpful and aid understanding, but you can't appeal to it in a court of law (so to speak).

I'm afraid that specifications from standard bodies like W3C, just like legal contracts, are written in formal language that the reader is expected to understand. It's worth persevering, because once you've got over the initial hurdle of some unfamiliar language, it's actually much easier to get a definitive answer to many of the kinds of questions that people ask on forums like this by referring to the official standard than by reading the tutorial sites that try to make it more friendly but lose precision in the process.

Comment: Thank you, @Michael Kay, for a very clear answer. I will keep persevering. (It would help if these formal docs would just have a sentence or two in a footnote explaining what you said.)

Comment: "...it's actually much easier to get a definitive answer to many of the kinds of questions that people ask on forums like this by referring to the official standard than by reading the tutorial sites that try to make it more friendly but lose precision in the process." Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: I'm sorry to sound stupid, but I'm still not sure: Does `non-normative` mean that such thing is not a part of official speification, but rather only an idea?

Comment: Non-normative text is part of the official specification, but is at least in theory redundant and inessential. Sometimes it consists of examples to help you check that you have understood the specification correctly, sometimes it gives notes to explain implications of what the specification says, sometimes it is purely editorial material like acknowledgements or references to background reading. None of those quite fit your term "only an idea"

Answer (score 9):

The reason we divide specs into "normative" and "non-normative" is so that 
people know which source to trust if they disagree. For instance, a Working 
Group might write a tutorial or a set of examples or a position paper that 
contains an error which contradicts the normative specification. The 
normative specification is the one you should trust.

Sometimes a Working Group will cover the same material in different ways in 
two normative specs. When they do this, they are saying that these two 
specifications *must* agree, and any disagreement between them is an error 
which must be corrected by the Working Group.

Comment: Thank you, @mikewied, for your response. It helped me to get a sense of why they were using this type of terminology. I also checked @mu is too short 's reference to normative in wikipedia. He is right. The explanation is very dense. Thanks.