# What's the difference between new(Struct) and &Struct{} in Go?

Tags: go

They seem to be the same:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type S struct {
    i int
}

func main() {
  var s1 *S = new(S)
  fmt.Println(s1)

  var s2 *S = &S{}
  fmt.Println(s2)  // Prints the same thing.
}
```

Update:

Hm. I just realized that there's no obvious way to initialize S.i using new. Is there a way to do that? `new(S{i:1})` does not seem to work :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals):

> As a limiting case, if a composite literal contains no fields at all, it creates a zero value for the type. The expressions `new(File)` and `&File{}` are equivalent.

Comment: Is there a way to initialize fields using new?

Comment: @allyourcode don't think so.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498998/how-to-initialize-members-in-go-struct

Comment: Does the documentation say then, why they have chosen to include the `new` function? I thought `go` was all about non overlapping functionality..

Comment: @ThomasAhle What about `x := 5` versus `var x = 5` versus `var x int = 5` versus `var x int; x = 5`? It has no shortage of overlapping and redundant ways to do the same thing, though a case can be made in many cases for providing a rich set of idioms to express the programmer's intention as accurately as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure whether Effective Go is [*normative*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422238/4108803), however the language specifications are less straightforward with respect to `new` vs `& {}`

Answer (score 2):

Not only do they give the same resulting value, but if we allocate something both ways and look at their values...

```
// Adapted from http://tour.golang.org/#30
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

func main() {
    v := &Vertex{}
    v2 := new(Vertex)
    fmt.Printf("%p %p", v, v2)
}
```

...we'll see that they are in fact allocated in consecutive memory slots. Typical output: `0x10328100 0x10328108`. I'm not sure if this is an implementation detail or part of the specification, but it does demonstrate that they're both being allocated from the same pool.

[Play around with the code here.](http://play.golang.org/p/e8jez3Qnsg)

As for initializing with new, according to [the language spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation): `The built-in function new takes a type T and returns a value of type *T. The memory [pointed to] is initialized as described in the section on initial values.` Because functions in go can't be overloaded, and this isn't a variadic function, there's no way to pass in any initialization data. Instead, go will initialize it with whatever version of `0` makes sense for the type and any member fields, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
Case 1: package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Drink struct {
    Name    string
    Flavour string
}

func main() {
    a := new(Drink)
    a.Name = "Maaza"
    a.Flavour = "Mango"
    b := a
    fmt.Println(&a)
    fmt.Println(&b)
    b.Name = "Frooti"

    fmt.Println(a.Name)

}//This will output Frooti for a.Name, even though the addresses for a and b are different.

Case 2:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Drink struct {
    Name    string
    Flavour string
}

func main() {
    a := Drink{
        Name:    "Maaza",
        Flavour: "Mango",
    }

    b := a
    fmt.Println(&a)
    fmt.Println(&b)
    b.Name = "Froti"

    fmt.Println(a.Name)

}//This will output Maaza for a.Name. To get Frooti in this case assign b:=&a.
```